# Image Conversion when manipulating the filebytes

Tags: c#, image

I have a problem. When images are saved in my database they are saved with the filebytes and there is a reference ID to this record. There is a .ashx file that will take this reference ID number and get the file info/file bytes and display the image or allow for the downloading of the image.

```
img src="/download.ashx?id=THEREFID
```

This above would display the image in on the page. If I just put a link to the .ashx page it would download the image. This is fine. However some of my images are saved as .TIF and I need to convert them to .jpeg.

I have a class called FileData

```
public string FileName;
public byte[] theData;
public long FileSizeBytes;
public string MIME;
public string Extension;
```

On my .ashx page I have a method that loads the above FileData class. Then the FileData class along with the HttpContext class gets sent to a method:

```
private void Process(HttpContext context, FileData file)
{
    context.Response.ContentTYpe = file.MIME;
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" 
        + file.FileName.Replace(' ', '_') 
        + file.FileExtension);
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.FileSizeBytes.ToString());
    context.Response.Expires = 0;
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(file.Data);
    context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

I need to find a way to convert this info to a jpeg. I am thinking maybe a temporary bitmap, convert it to .jpeg, then get the file bytes from this?

Answer (score 0):

i would do it as you intended...

more or less like that:

```
                System.Drawing.Bitmap tiffImage;
                using(BinaryWriter  baseWriter = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream()))
                {
                    baseWriter.Write(tiffData);
                    baseWriter.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    tiffImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(baseWriter.BaseStream);
                }

                MemoryStream jpgStream = new MemoryStream();

                tiffImage.Save(jpgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                jpgStream.Position = 0;
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(jpgStream))
                {
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(br.ReadBytes(jpgStream.Length));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is what I did:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(file.Data));
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)img;

EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters();
encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 50L);

ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image.jpeg");
MemoryStream newImage = new MemoryStream();

bmp.Save(newImage, codecInfo, encoderParams);

byte[] newData = newImage.ToArray();

//Overwritting the original FileData
file.Data = newData;
file.FileSizeBytes = newData.Length;
file.MIME = "image/jpeg";
```